# Duda sobre normalizar datos en base de datos - Mejores prácticas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un modelo de base de datos MySQL en la cual se va a almacenar el mantenimiento que se le va haciendo a unos equipos informáticos.
Varias tablas son irrelevantes para el caso, así que solo pondré resumidas las que me generan la duda.

Las tablas clave en cuestión son 3: 
`Hardware` (almacena el serial, marca y modelo de los equipos), 
`Feature`, los items de mantemiento que el usuario podrá agregar o deshabilitar y finalmente `Maint`, donde se van a ir acumulando los mantenimientos.

Las dos primeras tablas tienen una estructura así:

```
+----------+    +---------+
| Hardware |    | Feature |
+----------+    +---------+
| id       |    | id      |
| label    |    | status  |
| brand    |    | descr   |
| model    |    +---------+
| ...etc   |
+----------+
```

Algunos registros de la tabla `Feature`:

```
+----+---------+-------------------------------------+
| id | status  | descr                               |
+----+---------+-------------------------------------+
|  4 |       1 | Limpieza Fisica                     |
|  5 |       0 | Actualizar Flash Player             |
|  6 |       1 | Defragmentar disco                  |
|  7 |       1 | Instalar actualizaciones de sistema |
+----+---------+-------------------------------------+
```

Mi duda es cómo almacenar los datos en la tercera tabla ya que los registros de la tabla Feature son variables en el tiempo, por ejemplo, en algún momento se instalaba "Flash Player" y ya no, así que en el `status` se deshabilita. Los datos se van a guardar en la tabla `Maint` (mantenimiento) y mi consulta es cuál sería la mejor práctica para almacenar los mantenimientos. 
Se me han ocurrido en mente 3 opciones

**Opcion 1**: Una tabla sencilla donde se va guardando un *Feature* del mantenimiento por cada registro.

```
+----------+
| Maint    |
+----------+
| id       |
| mdate    |
| hardw_id |
| feat_id  |
| user_id  |
+----------+
```

(*Maint*)

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------+
| id | mdate      | hardw_id | user_id | feat_id |
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------+
| 52 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |       4 |
| 53 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |       5 |
| 54 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |       6 |
| 55 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |       7 |
| 56 | 2019-06-12 |        7 |       3 |       4 |
| 57 | 2019-06-12 |        7 |       3 |       6 |
| 58 | 2019-06-24 |       10 |      28 |       6 |
| 59 | 2019-06-24 |       10 |      28 |       7 |
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------+
```

Ventajas: Es solo una tabla, y los datos son intuitivos. Desventaja: Alta redundancia de datos en algunas columnas

**Opcion 2**: Meter los datos de forma serializada (JSON, XML, etc)

```
+----------+
| Maint    |
+----------+
| id       |
| mdate    |
| hardw_id |
| user_id  |
| value    |
+----------+
```

(*Maint*)

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+------------------+
| id | mdate      | hardw_id | user_id | value            |
+----+------------+----------+---------+------------------+
| 21 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 | JSON{4, 5, 6, 7} |
| 22 | 2019-06-12 |        7 |       3 | JSON{4, 6}       |
| 23 | 2019-06-24 |       10 |      28 | JSON{6, 7}       |
+----+------------+----------+---------+------------------+
```

Ventajas: Practicamente nula redundancia de datos y compresión máxima de información. Desventajas: Hacer reportes y estadísticas supondría más trabajo al tener que leer todos los registros y pre-procesarlos antes de poder trabajar con ellos. La tabla `Feature` quedaría sin una relación.

**Opcion 3**: Crear otra tabla adicional para meter los datos.

```
+----------+    +----------+
| Maint    |    | MData    |
+----------+    +----------+
| id       |    | id       |
| mdate    |    | maint_id |
| hardw_id |    | feat_id  |
| user_id  |    +----------+
+----------+
```

(*Maint*)

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+
| id | mdate      | hardw_id | user_id |
+----+------------+----------+---------+
| 21 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |
| 22 | 2019-06-12 |        7 |       3 |
| 23 | 2019-06-24 |       10 |      28 |
+----+------------+----------+---------+
```

(*MData*)

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | maint_id | feat_id |
+----+----------+---------+
| 92 |       21 |       4 |
| 93 |       21 |       5 |
| 94 |       21 |       6 |
| 95 |       21 |       7 |
| 96 |       22 |       4 |
| 97 |       22 |       6 |
| 98 |       23 |       6 |
| 99 |       23 |       7 |
+----+----------+---------+
```

Ventajas: Los datos no son tan redundantes y son facilmente usables con un JOIN. Desventeja: Una tabla extra (aunque no creo que suponga mucho en cuanto rendimiento).

¿Tendrán ustedes una mejor opción o alguno de mis modelos es el adecuado para el caso?

Comment: de cuantos datos hablamos? porque JSON deberia ser un NO siempre (que alguien me demuestre lo contrario) y en la opcion 1 no veo ninguna redundancia de datos.. vos donde la ves?

Comment: @gbianchi La opción 1 veo repetidas mdate, hardw_id y user_id, creo innecesariamente. Si en la tabla Features hubieran 20 registros activos, serían 20 veces repetidos esos campos por cada mantenimiento. Le pregunté a alguien y me recomienda la 3ra opción. A propósito de los JSON, otra persona me dice que se le puede meter un Elastic Search a eso para sacar estadísticas fácilmente, pero bueno, ya eso es otro tema.

Comment: Creo que has resumido muy bien las posibilidades. Podrías agregar un modelo, que no me parece práctico en este caso, si los mantenimientos tuvieran un número fijo de `features`, por ejemplo 10, dónde en tu tabla `maint` habría 10 columnas `feature1..10`. Para mí, las opciones a elegir son la 1 o la 3. La pregunta básica que me haría, los `features` de cada mantenimiento, ¿tienen datos particulares? en cuyo caso sin duda la opción 3. También, técnicamente hablando en la opción 1 deberías tener un `main_id` único por mantenimiento y la PK sí, sería `main_id + feat_id`

Comment: Esa "seria" la respuesta @PatricioMoracho.. pero sigo dudando de si es una pregunta valida... tecnicamente FN3 seria la 3.. usar elastic search para datos que no son desectructurados como esto, es matar mosquitos con cañones... un sinsentido...

Comment: @gbianchi, coincido, la pregunta está muy bien planteada, pero lamentablemente apunta a obtener opiniones. Esperemos que los comentarios  ayuden.

Comment: Si te animas arma eso como respuesta @PatricioMoracho. Aunque la pregunta podria ser basada en opiniones (es mas, los 3 modelos tiene pro y con), en FN3 lo correcto es la ultima.. si la encaramos para ese lado, vale...

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias a todos por sus comentarios, la 3 será la opción elegida entonces. Como mencionaron, si alguien se anima a escribir, lo aceptaré como respuesta válida y cerrar el tema cc @PatricioMoracho

Comment: Entiendo que ya se ha tomado una decisión, aun así opinaría. Yo optaría por la primera propuesta por ser la mas simple. Y coincido con @gbianchi que no hay redundancia. En ambos casos - 1 o 3, optaría por una clave compuesta y eliminaría la columna *id* (en el caso 3 - de las dos tablas). Es solo por opinar ya que me parece interesante la prgunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En primer lugar tienes una regla de negocio que podríamos resumir en:

> 1 Mantenimiento = 1 usuario = 1 Hardware = múltiples features

Ahora veamos algunos hechos de cada modelo:

#### Modelo 1: una única tabla

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------+
| id | mdate      | hardw_id | user_id | feat_id |
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------+
| 52 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |       4 |
| 52 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |       5 |
| 52 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |       6 |
| 52 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |       7 |
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------+
```

**Nota**: entiendo que el `id` es el del mantenimiento, por lo que en realidad el `id = 52` es un único mantenimiento con múltiples `features`.

El principal problema de este modelo, es que no es consistente con la regla de negocio, al contrario, pienso que esta tabla no es nada intuitiva. Si no conociera el modelo de datos y solo viera la tabla, podría suponer que un mantenimiento podría tener múltiples usuarios, o múltiple hardaware en función de cada `feature`. Recién agrupando todas las filas por el `id`, con suerte descubriría que el usuario y el hardware es siempre el mismo para cada mantenimiento. La redundancia de datos es evidente, pero, no hay que verlo por el lado del malgasto de memoria (a menos que se trate de un sistema embebido), el problema es que un modelo redundante en datos como éste, es frágil para mantener la lógica de negocios. Imaginemos cualquier situación, cualquier modificación equivocada o maliciosa, dónde los datos terminaran siendo esto

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------+
| id | mdate      | hardw_id | user_id | feat_id |
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------+
| 52 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |       4 |
| 52 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |       5 | 
| 52 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      29 |       6 | <- 
| 52 | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      29 |       7 | <-
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------+
```

Si te encontrarás con esta situación y no sabes nada, ¿Cuál es el usuario del mantenimiento 52, el `user_id` 28 o el 29? Esto "rompe" la regla inicial, y con toda seguridad "rompe" cualquier capa de aplicación que asuma y muestre información sobre el supuesto de 1 mantenimiento = 1 usuario. ¿Una actualización errónea o maliciosa también puede ocurrir con los otros modelos? absolutamente, podemos modificar el usuario para que no sea el que efectivamente corresponda, pero el modelo sigue siendo consistente.

Por otro lado, los datos organizados de esta forma, exigen más al motor para un conjunto importante de consultas. Por ejemplo, si interesa ver los datos de cada mantenimiento, digamos, listar los mantenimientos de determinado período, estás obligado siempre a agrupar innecesariamente la información, para ver solo una única fila para cada mantenimiento.

Hay una variante de este modelo que podríamos llamar:

#### Modelo 1b

De hecho es algo más consistente con la regla de negocio y minimiza el problema del agrupamiento. La idea es un tabla del tipo `cabecera / detalle`, algo así:

```
+----+---+------------+----------+---------+---------+
| id | T | mdate      | hardw_id | user_id | feat_id |
+----+---+------------+----------+---------+---------+
| 52 | C | 2019-05-21 |        3 |      28 |         |
| 52 | D |            |          |         |       4 |
| 52 | D |            |          |         |       5 |
| 52 | D |            |          |         |       6 |
| 52 | D |            |          |         |       7 |
+----+---+------------+----------+---------+---------+
```

La columna `T` es el Tipo de registro: `C`abecera o `D`etalle, las celdas en blanco son en realidad `NULLs`, eventualmente también podrían estar los datos repetidos. Tenemos una única fila para los datos del mantenimiento y `n` filas para los `features`. Tampoco es necesario hacer un `group by` para ver únicamente los datos del mantenimiento (solo hay que filtrar las filas de cabecera). Podemos implementar `inner joins` cabecera/detalle apuntando a la misma tabla pero con distinto tipo de registro. Es una variante algo mejor que tu **Modelo 1**, te lo comento a modo informativo, es un modelo algo antiguo, de hecho muy habitual cuando no había bases relacionales, aunque todavía, en mi caso al menos, tengo algunos sistemas heredados que tienen tablas de este tipo.

#### Modelo 2

Una tabla por mantenimiento y una columna donde serializamos los `features`. Sin duda, aquí ya tenemos un modelo consistente con la regla de negocio inicial. La cuestión es: (1) cuanto necesitaremos trabajar con los `features` y (2) Los límites de espacio que impone la columna. Con respecto al punto (2), independientemente de la forma en que serializemos los `features` (CSV, Json, Xml) siempre tendremos un límite máximo, tal vez nunca lleguemos a ese límite, pero el límite existe y siempre será menor a guardar los `features` de forma "vertical" (Modelo 3). Pero sin duda el punto más importante a tener en cuenta, es cuanto y como necesitaremos acceder a los `features`.

> La des-serializacion de una columna de valores, o lo que es lo mismo, la transformación de un conjunto de datos "horizontal" a uno "vertical", es un proceso por lo general costoso para el motor y de alguna manera "anti-natural", al menos desde el punto de vista del lenguaje SQL

Imagina una consulta del tipo: "Quiero ver cuantos `features` de determinado tipo se han realizado en toda la historia", no parece una consulta demasiado atípica. Para resolverla, no queda otra solución que "desempaquetar" los "features" de todos las filas solo para encontrar un en particular. Sin duda un costo importante si lo comparamos con el siguiente modelo.

#### Modelo 3

No hay mucho que decir, en el contexto de una base de datos relacional, sin duda, este es el modelo más natural y conciso para manejar tu modelo de datos. Tener un tabla más, es un impacto realmente despreciable frente a las ventajas que aporta. Podrías eventualmente simplificar `MData` y eliminar directamente la columna `id`, dejando únicamente como `PK` las columnas `maint_id + feat_id`. Con este modelo, puedes encarar casi cualquier tipo de consulta con las herramientas más básicas y estándar de SQL.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el concepto ha quedado claro.

Answer (score 0):

Empecemos por considerar que una base de datos debería estar en [3ª forma Normal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tercera_forma_normal), sería recomendable echar un vistazo a lo que es y tenerlo claro.
Y luego trabajar con vistas para representar la información, en la que, por medio de SQL te traes una unión de talbas con , por ejemplo:

- "la última feature para todo Mantenimiento = usuario = Hardware"
- Historico de features para 1 mantenimiento-usuario-hardware

De esta forma se evita la redundancia en los datos, se respeta la integridad referencial y facilita el acceso a la información con el mínimo de accesos a la BBDD.